# Can't send mail with gmail smtp server (in discourse)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, gmail, discourse

I'm trying to setup [discourse](http://www.discourse.org), which is a rails3 webapp, but have some problems configuring smtp with gmail smtp server.

I have registered a new gmail account yesterday, and I can logged in browser and email-client software.

Then I configure discourse, in the file `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address   => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port      => "587",
  :user_name => "smtp4shuzu@gmail.com",
  :password  => "12345678",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :domain => "shuzhu.org",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Start the `sidekiq` which is used to sending the mails in the background:

```
nohup bundle exec sidekiq > log/sidekiq.log 2>&1 &
```

Then start discourse in production mode:

```
rails server -e production -d
```

But it doesn't work. I can see some errors in `sidekiq.log`:

> 2013-03-01T03:06:02Z 30687 TID-qib28 WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"Jobs::UserEmail", "args"=>[{"type"=>"signup", "user_id"=>42, "email_token"=>"b40a21ece2b14586e346abfd96685975", "current_site_id"=>"default"}], "jid"=>"558bb6bd5aa36cfc8d3d1e91", "error_message"=>"Connection refused - connect(2)", "error_class"=>"Errno::ECONNREFUSED", "failed_at"=>2013-03-01 03:06:02 UTC, "retry_count"=>0}
>   2013-03-01T03:06:02Z 30687 TID-qib28 WARN: Connection refused - connect(2)
>   2013-03-01T03:06:02Z 30687 TID-qib28 WARN: /home/discourse/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:540:in `initialize'
>   /home/discourse/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:540:in`open'
>   /home/discourse/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:540:in `tcp_socket'

I have tried all kinds of smtp settings, but none of them works.

---

**UPDATE**:

Per @Basil's answer, I just tried:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address   => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port      => 587,
  :user_name => "smtp4shuzu",
  :password  => "12345678",
  :authentication => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

But it has the same error. The domain `shuzu.org` is the domain of my site, I was thinking I should passing it to smtp. Now I removed it, but still not working.

Comment: try adding           :domain => "gmail.com", and then restart your server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At last, I found the (stupid) reason.

I should start `sidekiq` in production mode:

```
nohup bundle exec sidekiq -e production > log/sidekiq.log 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the quotes around the port

```
  :port      => 587,
```

Also, I don't understand why your email address is @gmail but your domain is @shuhzu... smtp settings should show the domain for your email account. If you have a custom gmail, i.e me@custom.com then domain would be custom.com. Here is an example of what smtp settings for your domain should be if you have a custom email address:

```
{
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587 ,
    :domain => "custom.com",
    :user_name => "some_email@custom.com",
    :password => "some_password",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just set up a new discourse instance in a docker container on my own ubuntu physical on site server and edited the app.yml to contain:

```
DISCOURSE_SMTP_ADDRESS: 'smtp.gmail.com'
DISCOURSE_SMTP_AUTHENTICATION: 'plain'
DISCOURSE_SMTP_PORT: 587
DISCOURSE_SMTP_USER_NAME: 'my.name@gmail.com'
DISCOURSE_SMTP_PASSWORD: 'myPa$$word'
DISCOURSE_SMTP_ENABLE_START_TLS: true
```

and it worked. Half the battle was knowing where to put single inverted commas (') and where not to.

Another way was available to me also - my ISP provides a relay smtp for it's static IP customers so I used this in app.yam:

```
DISCOURSE_SMTP_ADDRESS: mail.myisp.tld
DISCOURSE_SMTP_AUTHENTICATION: none
DISCOURSE_SMTP_PORT: 25
```

and it works for me also.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is useful to uncomment the following line in `/var/discourse/containers/app.yml`:

```
 ## If you want to set the 'From' email address for your first registration, uncomment and change:
 ## After getting the first signup email, re-comment the line. It only needs to run once.
  - exec: rails r "SiteSetting.notification_email='noreply@YOURDOMAIN.com'"
```

You should put here the address on behalf of which all Discourse's emails should come. By default Discourse will try to use **your forum's domain name**, but it may not be allowed by your SMTP. For example, your forum is at `forum.example.com`, while your Gmail SMTP only allows emails from `example.com`.

For SMTP without authentication just leave the auth fields like this:

```
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_USER_NAME:
  DISCOURSE_SMTP_PASSWORD:
```

and after everything is saved:

```
./launcher rebuild app
```

Once emails are working, **you can re-comment this line** (with `SiteSetting`).

You can even just set this `SiteSetting` via console, but it's more difficult than uncommenting/re-commenting a single line and re-build the container, so I'll not elaborate on this.

Answer (score 0):

On my install, which is one of those pre-made image thingies (Bitnami), I just had to run this:

```
/opt/discourse-0.9.5-0/ctlscript.sh start discourse_sidekiq
```

Anyone know how I can automate this so that it happens on startup?